# Is there a nice formulation for the convolution of a Bernoulli and Poisson random variable?

Tags: probability, distributions

Are there any special properties about this convolution that permit an easy formulation for the resulting R.V? I feel like there should be, given that:

1. The Poisson process can be thought of as the continuous analog of the Bernoulli process.
2. There are nice formulas for the convolution of each of these processes, e.g. the sum of Bernoulli R.V.s with same probability of success is the binomial distribution, and the sum of Poisson R.V.s is another Poission RV.

I note that from [this Q/A](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44587/sum-of-binomial-and-poisson-random-variables) that such a formulation does not exist if we consider a binomial R.V. instead of a Bernoulli R.V.

As noted in the comments, it is easy to write down the convolution of these R.V.s:

Let $P(X = k)$ be Poisson distributed with mean $\lambda$. Let $Q(X = k)$ denote the shifted R.V of $P(X = k)$ such that $Q(X = k) = P(X = k - 1)$.

Then, the R.V. $R(X = k)$ we are after has mass function given by:

$R(X = k) = pQ(X = k-1) + (1-p)P(x = k)$.

where $p$ is the probability of success for the Bernoulli R.V.

Comment: In your linked question, Dilip said that there is no simplification.  Also I don't see how the Poisson process is the continuous analog of the Bernoulli process.  The Poisson process is the limit of the Binomial process holding mean constant and letting $n$ go to infinity.

Comment: the linked question says that there is no simplification in the general case where the number of trials is greater than 1, but that doesn't necessary imply that there is no simplification in this simpler case?

Comment: Maybe you're right.  Did you try to simplify it?

Comment: as per your other comment regarding bernoulli/binomial processes, I am only quoting from http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-436j-fundamentals-of-probability-fall-2008/lecture-notes/MIT6_436JF08_lec20.pdf

Comment: I don't know how to simplify it, although the convolution is simple to write down in this case.

Comment: Why don't you start by writing it down since the answerer will probably start there?

Comment: sure, i've written it down now. It looks nice enough to me, being some weighted average of a poisson and shifted poisson, but I have no idea whether it actually simplifies any further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X \sim \text{Bernoulli}(p)$ and $Y \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda)$
then $Z = X+Y$ takes on values $0, 1, 2, \ldots$.

It follows straightforwardly that
\begin{align}P\{Z = k\} &= \begin{cases}P\{X=0, Y=0\},& k = 0,\\
 \\
P\{X=0, Y=k\} + P\{X=1, Y=k-1\}, & k \geq 1,\end{cases}
\end{align}

No further simplification is possible unless the joint
probabilities have specific properties. For example, if
$X$ and $Y$ are *independent* random variables, then the joint
probabilities factor into the product of the marginal
probabilities and we have that
\begin{align}P\{Z = k\} &= \begin{cases}P\{X=0\}P\{Y=0\},& k = 0,\\
 \\
P\{X=0\}P\{Y=k\} + P\{X=1\}P\{Y=k-1\}, & k \geq 1,\end{cases}\\
 \\
&= \begin{cases}
(1-p)e^{-\lambda}, & k = 0,\\
 \\
(1-p)e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{k}}{k!} + p\cdot e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}, & k \geq 1.\end{cases}
\end{align}

I suppose that we could write that last line as 
$$(1-p)e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{k}}{k!} + p\cdot e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{k-1}}{(k-1)!} 
= \left.\left.e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}
\right[p + (1-p)\frac{\lambda}{k} \right]$$
and count it as a simplification. Or, perhaps even better,
use the version in OP Alex's comment to combine both
lines and write

$$P\{Z = k\} = \left.\left.e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{k}}{k!} \right[\frac{pk}{\lambda} + 1-p\right], k = 0, 1, 2, \ldots $$
but I don't think this sort of stuff is referred to as a
*deformation* of a Poisson random variable.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Sorry, I forgot to mention in my OP that my random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent, which could only be assumed from my formulation of the join probabilities.

Comment: if we write the last line as: $\left.\left.e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{k}}{k!}
\right[\frac{pk}{\lambda} + 1-p\right]$ then I suppose we can consider this as a deformation of the original Poisson R.V., which I think is a very nice result.

Comment: now I wonder whether the question from http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44587/sum-of-binomial-and-poisson-random-variables can be answered/interpreted in the same way.